# Receiving info from a form

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I'm new here, new to programming as well so let me apologize in advance because this has probably been covered or may even be common knowledge.  I'm in a bit of a timecrunch tho.

I've got a small repair business that I have been planning on running over the road from a website rather than having a traditional brick and mortar shop.  Up until a couple weeks ago, I had been messing with an editor on a commerce site intending on working from a simple contact form until i could get a better handle on things, but i soon discovered that the site wouldn't allow me to store the data on the backend like i needed to.  Having already at that point taken a few video lessons covering bootstrap (the commerce site used this, and I found that it was easier to manipulate things thru the code rather than the console it provided) I elected to just drop the commerce site and just put up a static page on google cloud to which i can later build on and link a mongodb to using mlab.

that said, I'm not fully committed to that plan, its just that there doesn't seem to be any out of the box editor that would allow me to work with the backend without learning one form of code or other, and after a week or so of research, mongodb and node.js seem to be the most plausible route for me to go given that I'm new and only know a little bit of javascript and html at this point (currently enrolled in an online program to catch up).

So here's where I'm at, I've built a contact form using an accordion menu from bootstrap.  I've got my form tag set

```
<form method="post" action="mailto:example@gmail.com" >
   <div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
      <div class="card">
         <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
               <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">Collapsible Group Item #1
               </a>
            </h5>
         </div>
         <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
             <div class="card-block">
                <div class = 'container form-group'>
                    <input type = 'text'>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
              <h5 class="mb-0">
                  <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">Collapsible Group Item #2
                  </a>
              </h5>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
              <div class="card-block">
                  <div class = 'container form-group'>
                    <input type = 'text'>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
           <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingThree">
               <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">Collapsible Group Item #3
                    </a>
               </h5>
           </div>
           <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
               <div class="card-block">
                  <div class = 'container form-group'>
                    <input type = 'text'>
                  </div>
               </div>
           </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card row justify-content-center">
           <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="submitForm">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" >Submit for Quote
                  </button>
           </div>    
      </div> 
   </div>
<form>
```

and at the bottom just before the accordion closing div i put my submit button.

Everything seems to be working properly, except of course the submit button sends a blank email.  I've read multiple solutions on here using php, but I'm typically not someone who is good with just cutting and pasting without fully understanding

what I'm doing, so I was wondering might there be another way to attach the filled out form using javascript in some fashion so that I can stick with learning just a couple of languages for now?  I've got access to ajax, angular, node, mean and mongo tutorial videos, I just don't know if the specific action that I'm trying to accomplish would fall under any of these.

I've got every intention of sitting through all of those courses and gaining a full understanding of javascript, however, having spent so much time fighting with the commerce site, I'm a bit behind on my launch and could really use this form being operational so that I can get work in to pay the bills while I focus on my studies and learn more code.

Comment: If you lack time, use Google Forms until you can get a server running. You can't just get a server up and running without the fundamental understanding of the language unless you get a cookie cutter service to do it for you.

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Comment: @zer00ne I was going to try to put my HTML document on google cloud services, I have the bootstrap 4 cdn linked to the page and everything is working except for the button not attaching the form info to the email it triggers.  I was getting ahead of myself talking about the database, I did so simply to indicate the direction I wanted to go in and possibly why I didn't want to go diving off into php for this one function.  But database aside, I just need the form emailed to me right now so that I can call the customer with a quote.

Comment: @Momin I didn't include the code earlier because it was long and i figured i would break the accordion trying to dissect it.  i edited the comment and added the bootstrap template i used with the form tag and submit button attached to it, so maybe that will clear things up?

Comment: @zer00ne i did check out google forms, that seems to require me to physically send the form to customers myself, meaning that I would need to know about the customer in advance which would more or less defeat the purpose.  I could see why you would suggest this tho, after another night of digging my alternative php solution seems to lie somewhere between express.js and a node.js module called nodemailer so it appears I've got a bit to go.  I'm assuming to get there it wouldn't be wise to skip courses like ajax and angular for the time being.

Comment: @BlakePowell This is exactly what you need: [**HTML Form Send Email via Google-Script without a Server**](https://github.com/dwyl/html-form-send-email-via-google-script-without-server)

Comment: @zer00ne wow man thanks, i that IS exactly what I needed.  I'll be able to take my time and learn things in the proper order now and maybe even enjoy it a little.  Coding sure beats the hell out of turning wrenches, thats for sure.  How do we mark ur comment as the answer to my question?

Comment: @BlakePowell you can mark a comment as a "like" but that's it. I avoid making answers that are just a link. I appreciate your acknowledgement though. Most importantly we have found a solution and you have put  in research and earnest effort into your question. Happy coding, sir.:)